Gradle Build Error: Unable to Run Gradle Build: Missing init.gradle File
I'm encountering a Gradle issue when building my Java project, the error message I get is the following:
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 
'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip'.
The specified initialization script 
'C:\Users\bchafi\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\redhat.java\1.35.1\config_win\org.eclipse.osgi\57\0\.cp\gradle\init\init.gradle'
does not exist.

In an attempt to resolve this, I tried to manually create the necessary folder structure where the init.gradle file would be located, but I realized that I do not have the init.gradle file available.
Additionally, I attempted to install Gradle manually by downloading it and placing it in C:\Gradle. After unzipping the distribution ZIP file, I made sure to set the GRADLE_HOME environment variable and added C:\Gradle\gradle-7.2\bin to my system's PATH.
Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue, and I am still unable to run my Gradle build.

Is this in VS Code? If so, can you check if a manual gradlew build fails with the same message? In the case where the manual build succeeds but VSCode thinks there's an error, I was able to resolve it by deleting .gradle and re-running my gradle init etc tasks.
